Rotations in $C\ell_{16,0}$
Consider the Clifford algebra $C\ell_{8,0}$. If $x\in C\ell_{8,0}$ and $u$ is a spinor in $C\ell_{8,0}$, then the rotations in this algebra can be written as
$$
x' = u x u^{-1}.
$$
Now consider $C\ell_{16,0}$. Due to Bott periodicity, we have $C\ell_{16,0} \simeq C\ell_{8,0} \otimes C\ell_{8,0}$.
My question is: does Bott periodicity imply that if $X \in C\ell_{16,0}$, then $X = x \otimes y$, with $x,y \in C\ell_{8,0}$? In addition, does it also imply that a general rotation in $C\ell_{16,0}$ can be written as
$$
uxu^{-1} \otimes wyw^{-1}
$$
where $u$ and $w$ are spinors of $C\ell_{8,0}$?

Your use of "spinor" is strange, it seems you mean "element of the group $Spin(16)$".
You don't need Bott periodicity for this; if $V = S\oplus T$ with $S\perp T$ then $$Cl(V) \cong Cl(S)\mathbin{\hat\otimes}Cl(T).$$ This means that $$Cl_{p_1+p_2,q_1+q_2} \cong Cl_{p_1,q_1}\mathbin{\hat\otimes}Cl_{p_2,q_2}.$$
It is not the case that $u_1$ and $u_2$ have to be elements of $Spin(8)$; they can in fact be any two elements of $Pin(8)$.
For example, let us write $C_1, C_2$ for the two copies of $Cl_{8,0}$ so that $Cl_{16,0}= C_1\mathbin{\hat\otimes}C_2$. If $e_1 \in C_1$ is a generator (i.e. a unit vector) and $e_9 \in C_2$ is a generator, then $u = e_1\otimes e_9 \in Spin(16)$.

Thanks for your answer! The really important point to me is the tensor product decomposition of things due to Bott periodicity. In other words, is working with $C\ell_{16,0}$ the same as working with $C\ell_{8,0} \otimes C\ell_{8,0}$? If so, it would be intuitive to me that I could express any rotation in $C\ell_{16,0}$ as a tensor product of smaller rotations of $C\ell_{8,0}$. Is this the case?

I addressed all of this in my answer. (1) This isn't really Bott periodicity, it's a much, much easier result. (2) You cannot decompose any rotation in $Cl_{16,0}$ into rotations of $Cl_{8,0}$; it's possible you have to decompose into two reflections of $Cl_{8,0}$.

I should also say: (3) Yes, working with $Cl_{8,0}\mathbin{\hat\otimes}Cl_{8,0}$ is the same as $Cl_{16,0}$ as long as you respect the grading (which is what that hat on the tensor product means).

Thank you for clarifying! One last question if possible: I was under the impression that the relation $C\ell_{16,0} = C\ell_{8,0} \otimes^{^} C\ell_{8,0}$ meant that we could view $C\ell_{16,0}$ as matrices with entries in $C\ell_{8,0}$. Is that equivalent to the grading you mean?

@user38680 The graded tensor product cannot be written in terms of matrices in any simple way like that. What it means is that if $y_1$ has grade $g_y$ and $x_2$ has grade $g_x$ then $$(x_1\otimes y_1)(x_2\otimes y_2) = (-1)^{g_xg_y}(x_1x_2)\otimes(y_1y_2).$$ However, after looking around some, I have realized there is an isomorphism using a non-graded tensor product (and which is more related to Bott periodicity; my bad for not being aware of this). If you really want matrices, I will have to think on this and revise my answer.
